# Why are energy eigenstates required to be bounded?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The [MIT lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_01.pdf) for Quantum Physics-II course says that for a solution $\psi(x)$ (to the time-independent Schrödinger Equation) to be acceptable, it is required to be continuous and bounded, and its first derivative needs to be bounded.

The requirement for a continuous eigenstate is understandable as the potentials usually considered forbid otherwise. However, I don't understand why the states and their first derivatives need to be bounded. The time-independent Schrödinger equation does not seem to put any such restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget that we're working in a Hilbert space - $L^2(\mathbb R)$, in this case.  The operators $\hat A$ can only act on elements in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, but their domains are typically further restricted to those $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $\Vert A \psi \Vert^2 < \infty$ and, for more general Hilbert spaces, further *still* by boundary conditions.

---

**Mathematical Interlude**

As the notes mention, this is a rather restrictive requirement. In many cases, it turns out to be *extremely* useful to extend this notion slightly by considering *distributions* on $L^2(\mathbb R)$.  A distribution$^\dagger$ is an object which eats an element of $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and spits out a complex number, and can typically be written as

$$D_\phi[\psi] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi^*(x) \psi(x) dx$$

for some function $\phi$, which we might call the *kernel* of the distribution (but usually we are sloppy and just call it "the distribution $\phi$"). In this expression, $\psi$ must belong to $L^2(\mathbb R)$, but the restrictions on $\phi$ are looser.  Of course, $\phi$ *could* be an element of $L^2(\mathbb R)$, in which case this expression reduces to the inner product $\langle \phi,\psi\rangle$, but this is not always the case; in particular, $\phi$ generally need not be normalizable.  In particular, delta functions$^{\dagger\dagger}$ $\delta(x-x_0)$ and plane waves $e^{ikx}$ are common distribution kernels.

Having done this, we can define the action of a self-adjoint operator $\hat A$ on $\phi$ as follows:

$$D_{\hat A\phi}[\psi] := D_\phi[\hat A\psi]$$
$$\iff \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\hat A\phi)^*(x) \psi(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi^*(x) (\hat A\psi)(x) dx$$

Operators such as the position and momentum observables do not actually have any eigenvectors in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, but if we extend them in this way then it turns out that they *do* have "generalized eigenvectors" which are *distributions* (the delta functions and plane waves, respectively).

---

This is, of course, too much math for a first pass through quantum mechanics. In *practice*, this can be distilled down to the following:

1. Observables with continuous spectra do not have eigenvectors in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ (that is, they do not have *normalizable* eigenvectors), but if we allow them to act on distributions (which do not have the normalizability requirement), then they have *generalized eigenvectors*.
2. In order for this procedure to be well-defined, we need certain regularity requirements on the distributions.  They need not be normalizable, but we must have that $D_{\hat A\phi}[\psi] = D_\phi[\hat A\psi] = \lambda D_\phi[\psi]$ is finite for all $\psi$ in the domain of $\hat A$.
3. It turns out that the proper choices for the regularity requirements of the Hamiltonian $\hat H = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x)$ are boundedness of the distribution and its first derivative, as per the notes.

---

$^\dagger$ In the interest of completeness, we usually consider **tempered** distributions, which only act on a very well-behaved *subset* of $L^2(\mathbb R)$. See the second to last paragraph in the introduction of [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Operations_on_distributions).  However, I feel that this detail is too far removed from the original question to be necessary.

$^{\dagger\dagger}$As noted by TBissinger, the delta function is not actually a function.  Instead, the delta distribution is defined via

$$\delta_{x_0}[\psi] := \psi(x_0)$$

That is, it is the distribution which simply evaluates the function at a point.  In order to make this look like other distributions which have kernels, we define the "delta function" and write

$$\delta_{x_0}[\psi] := \psi(x_0) \simeq \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-x_0) \psi(x) dx$$

and simply note that $\delta(x-x_0)$ is a purely formal symbol which should not be thought of as a function in the usual sense.

Comment: Very good answer. Just an aside because you are being mathematically concise: the $\delta$-function is not a function and does thus not qualify as a distribution kernel. One uses the integral notation with the "kernel" to symbolize the distribution $\delta_x[f] = f(x)$, but it is just a symbolic notation.

Comment: @TBissinger Yes, I am aware.  Given the context, however, I felt it appropriate to meet the OP halfway :)

Comment: @TBissinger That being said, I'll add your note to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: A clarification: notes say that we do not restrict ourselves to normalisable $\psi(x)$s (they can be outside the Hilbert space). Are you saying that these $\psi$s are kernels of distributions if not a part of Hilbert space?

Comment: @BigBrother Yes, precisely.

Comment: @BigBrother In order for $D_{\hat H \phi}[\psi] = \lambda D_{\phi}[\psi]$ (so $\phi$ is a "generalized eigenvector"), we must have that $D_{\hat H\phi}[\psi] = \int \phi^*(x) (\hat H\psi)(x) dx$ be well-defined for all $\psi$ in the domain of $\hat H$.  In this case, that means that $\psi,\psi',$ and $\psi''$ are all in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.  One can then ask what restrictions must be put on $\phi$ to make this true - this is what gives rise to the requirement that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ be bounded, with $\phi$ continuous.  Deriving this is quite technical, but that is the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Eigenstates are resonant standing wave patterns. Standing waves occur with boundaries.

Comment: IMHO this has nothing to do with the above question. The OP asks why for every energy eigenfunction $\psi_E(x)$ and its derivative, there must exist a constant $C\in{[}0,\infty)$ such that $|\psi_E(x)|\leq C$ for all $x$ in the domain of $\psi_E(x)$. This required *boundedness* of $\psi_E(x)$ has nothing to do with actual physical boundaries.

Comment: Fields can also act as boundaries.